# Cannot use document.getElementById() in global scope

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

When I try this on the global scope:

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML ="Howdy mate";
```

It does not work and firebug reports the error:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById is null
```

But the same instruction works well when inside a function:

```
function sayHello(){
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML ="Howdy mate";
}
```

I am yet to find any literature to explain this behaviour. Can anyone help?

EDIT: @All, the correct error message was

`document.getElementById("p1") is null`
not

`Window.getElementById("p1") is not a function`

as earlier stated. I have corrected.

Comment: can you jsfiddle part of code?

Comment: it's not a project. I'm learning javascript, so just trying out different instructions on my "playground" javascript\html document. So I'm guessing `document.getElementById()` don't need to be inside some local scope to work?

Comment: I suspect that you've accidentally used a comma instead a dot between `document` and `getElementById`. That's a realistic mistake, and matches the error message (the other option is that you've overridden the `document` variable, which is extremely unlikely).

Comment: @RobW, no comma. I used dot.

Comment: If you get that error message, that means you're not using `document.getElementById` - you might be using something like `getElementById`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

could be you're calling `document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML ="Howdy mate";`
before the element is loaded?

http://jsbin.com/abejiz/1/edit vs http://jsbin.com/abejiz/2/edit

Comment: Hmm, it's possible. My script code is actually in an external file and loaded with the `src=""` attribute of `<script>` tag, which in turn is located within `<head>` tag. So it's likely the code is executed before  the `<body>` is even loaded? Am I making sense? Like I said: I'm learning...

Comment: The error message corresponding to this would then be `document.getElementById(...) is null`, which is different from the one in the question.

Comment: @ RobW yes, you are right. the correct error message is `document.getElementById(...) is null` Sorry about the mixup. So is the above above answer correct?

Comment: I tend to load scripts as far down the doc as I can, usually in the footer `require_once` if possible, for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

@All, I revised my code following @user2264587's answer. The problem was that I had my javascript code loaded to the `<head>` tag of the document while the `<p>` element with `id="p1"` was located in the `<body>`. So the javascript instruction was actually being executed before the `<p>` element was loaded. I have now placed code inside `<body>` and after `<p>`:

```
<body>
...
<p id="p1"><p>
<script>
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML ="Howdy mate";
</script>

</body>
```

It works fine.